# How to display the data of array inside the array in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
data = [
    {
        rows: [
            { name: 'a'}
        ]
    },
    {
        rows: [
            { name: 'b'}
        ]
    }
    {
        rows: []
    }
]
```

what I'm trying to do here is to get the rows data. which is like this.

expected output:

```
data = [
    {
        name: 'a'
    },
    {
        name: 'b'
    }
];
```

where it will remove the empty array and it will merge on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Approach 1:

You can use reduce on your array as below -

```js
var data = [
    {
        rows: [
            { name: 'a'}
        ]
    },
    {
        rows: [
            { name: 'b'}
        ]
    },
    {
        rows: []
    }
]

var reducedSet = [];
data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex) => {
  var currentRows = currentValue.rows;
  var rowLength = currentRows && currentRows.length
  if (rowLength) {
    for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
            accumulator.push(currentRows[i]);
        }
    return accumulator;
  }
}, reducedSet);

console.log(reducedSet);
```

### Approach 2:

Alternatively, you can also do it as below -

```js
var data = [
    {
        rows: [
            { name: 'a'}
        ]
    },
    {
        rows: [
            { name: 'b'}
        ]
    },
    {
        rows: []
    }
];


var result = data.filter(f => f.rows && f.rows.length && f.rows.length > 0).map((currentValue) => {
  return currentValue.rows;
}).flat();

console.log(result);
```

Above code first filters out the empty rows and then maps the out the data and finally flattens the result.

Answer (score 1):

```js
data = [
    {
        rows: [
            { name: 'a'},
        ]
    },
    {
        rows: [
            { name: 'b'},
        ]
    },
    {
        rows: []
    }
]

let mappedData = data.map(obj => {
    return obj.rows.map(obj2 => {
        return {
            name: obj2.name
        }
    })
 })

mappedData = mappedData.flat()

console.log(mappedData)
```

Try something like that, I guess that's what you want from what I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

This might help. The solution provided takes into account that there might be multiple `name` inside a single `rows`.

```
let data = [] // YOUR OBJECT IN THE QUESTION

    let data2: any = []
    data.forEach(el => {
    if(el.rows.length > 0) {
    data2 = [...data2, ...el.rows];
       
        }
})


console.log('data2', data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to one-line it with modern Javascript, this is the way.

```
const transform = (inData) => inData.reduce((outData, { rows }) => outData.concat(rows), []);
```

Basically, create a new array, then for each entry in inData extract the content of the `rows` property and add it to the array.

Answer (score -1):

```
data.filter(x => {
  x.rows !== [];
});
```

You could filter the array.